# How To Set An MSBuild Condition on the MSBuild Version

Tags: msbuild, mono, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

Is there a Condition I can set to change the `TargetFrameworks` on a given project depending on the version on MSBuild itself?

I have a solution which is a mixture of .NetFramework 4.8, NetStandard2 and .net 6 libraries.

I'm trying to get the solution building under Mono on a Linux host but I have to select a specific MSBuild to use in Rider - I can choose `17` from `net 7` which will build the `net core` stack or `15` from Mono which builder the `net48` libraries - Neither will do both.

To work around this, I'm trying to adapt the project files to adjust the `TargetFrameworks` property appropriately. A bit like this...

```
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(MSBuildVersion)' == '15'">netstandard2.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(MSBuildVersion)' != '15'">netstandard2.0;net48;net6</TargetFrameworks>
```

From a pseudo-logic perspective, this would let the code build correctly and just ignore any code building for the `net6` builds.

For now I'm doing this...

````
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">netstandard2.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">netstandard2.0;net48;net6</TargetFrameworks>
    ```
````

Comment: MSBuild is the build engine and will build both .Net Framework and .Net/.Net Core in both v15 and v17. What commands are you running to build? How did you arrive at the conclusion that "neither will do both"?

Comment: You can't use both on Linux - You can on Windows; largely because Mono doesn't go higher than MSBuild 15 and you need that to build the .net Framework libraries. Both will build `netstandard`.

Comment: I missed that you are working on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual condition check should be against `MSBuildAssemblyVersion`.

```xml
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == '17.0' ">net6.0;netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == '16.0' ">netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
```

Copied from

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/12.5.1/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj

But seriously, migrate away from Mono when you can.

Comment: Migration isn't an option with our current stack - we'd be looking at complete rewrites in key areas - I'd have done it already if it was up to me, but it's not - too many costly dependencies to rework first.